# Problems implementing vector as a data container C++

Tags: c++, class, stdvector

I need to read data from a file and send it to a vector to perform some calculations with them. The data looks like this:

- 0 524 36 12 8 7 96 0 2
- 1 11 22 55 77 88 88 96 15
- 78 45 65 32 78 98 65 54 12

I managed to put the data in a "istringstream", it change with each iteration as it should, but I cannot put the data in the vector, it keeps adding just the first line of the file (e.g 0 524 36 12 8 7 96 0 2).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::ifstream input;
  std::string strInput;
  std::istringstream strData;
  std::vector<int> vectData;

  input.open("input.txt");

  for (int idx = 0; idx < 3; idx++)
  {
    std::getline(input >> std::ws, strInput, '\n');
    strData.str(strInput);
  
    int idy;
    //int index = 0;
    while(strData >> idy)
    {
      vectData.push_back(idy);
      //++index;
    }

    std::cout << strData.str() << std::endl;
    for (auto i:vectData)
    {
      std::cout<< i << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n' <<  std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I hope I have improved the question this time, thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: Do you know that `.resize` does not free the occupied memory allocated for a million of int? You might forget `push_back` that would allow you to avoid allocation of a million of int.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I tried that without using resize, it keeps giving me the same error. It calculates the first parameter the way it should, but for the second and the third one it keeps using the data of the first line.

 If I display the "istringstream" it changes accordingly.

Comment: There is no `vectDatos`, btw. How about a proper [mcve] ? Hint: If we can copy, paste, compile, and run, **only** the code you post *verbatim*, which means you also provide `#include` directives, a runnable `main`, etc., using **only** input data you also provide if needed for the reproduction, and we can reproduce your issue, I can near-guarantee we can tell you what the problem is and the solution to fix it. As a bonus, it is literally impossible to introduce "typos" when you copy/paste *functioning code* that produces your issue.  So... help us help *you*.

Comment: "I need to read data from a ".txt" file" - a file extension means *nothing*. A file can contain* anything* and be named *anything*. Don't rely on file names to tell you *anything*.

Comment: *it seems that the vector only stores the data of the first line* The alternative explanation is that the vector stores the data correctly, but that you are making an error in the way that you access the data. Try not to make assumptions when you are bug hunting. There's not enough information here to tell what is the actual problem.

Comment: *I'm having a rough time with vector in general* -- Then take a step back, and write a simple `main` that takes a vector, reads in the data, and outputs what you read.  You wrote too much code 1) That has nothing to do with vectors, i.e. `Statistics` and 2) Goes beyond what you can handle with vector.  The way a good programmer approaches this is to again, write a small program that tests things they are not familiar with.  Then when they get comfortable with things, then they incorporate that into a larger program.

Comment: There are no apparent errors in the posted code. It could all be correct (but it might not be of course). There's too much missing to say anything definite. If you can't create a [mre] then at least post a little more code. How does `strData` get initialised for instance. I can easily think of possible errors there. but I'm not going to guess until I can see the code.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your debugger on `vectData.push_back(idy);` . You're going to find it only hits when parsing the first line. After that the stream state is in error and it will never hit again, therefore the vector is not modified thereafter (nor is it cleared between lines, which is a flat bug regardless). The `str` member to set a string does *not* clear stream error state, so the same state that stopped the `while` loop prior will prevent it from continuing unless (a) it is cleared, or (b) just use a loop-local string stream  *inside* the for-loop in the first place.

Comment: It was a small thing after all. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it keeps adding just the first line of the file

That's because it is the only one it has. You seem to be of the impression that the `str` setter of `std::istringstream` resets the stream state from its prior error/eof condition. It doesn't. Since you're reusing the same `strData` member on each for-loop iteration, only the first one pushes through and fills the vector. After that the stream is in fail-state (by design, since that is what broke the inner-while-loop). When processing the next line, the stream is still in fail-state, and the while loop is effectively skipped.

Your options are numerous. For this trivial example I'd probably just do this, the most minimal change I can muster (which also fixes resetting the vector).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream input;
    std::string strInput;

    input.open("input.txt");

    for (int idx = 0; idx < 3; idx++)
    {
        std::getline(input >> std::ws, strInput, '\n');
        std::istringstream strData(strInput); // moved here

        std::vector<int> vectData; // also moved here
        int idy;
        while (strData >> idy)
        {
            vectData.push_back(idy);
        }

        std::cout << strData.str() << std::endl;
        for (auto i : vectData)
        {
            std::cout << i << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n'
                  << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Another considerably more concise and arguably more robust possibility is just this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream input("input.txt");
    if (input.is_open())
    {
        std::string strInput;
        while (std::getline(input, strInput))
        {
            std::cout << strInput << '\n';

            std::istringstream strData(strInput);
            std::vector<int> vectData {
                std::istream_iterator<int>(strData),
                std::istream_iterator<int>()
            };

            for (auto i : vectData)
            {
                std::cout << i << ' ';
            }
            std::cout << "\n\n";
        }
    }
}
```

**Output** (for the given sample input)

```
0 524 36 12 8 7 96 0 2
0 524 36 12 8 7 96 0 2 

1 11 22 55 77 88 88 96 15
1 11 22 55 77 88 88 96 15 

78 45 65 32 78 98 65 54 12
78 45 65 32 78 98 65 54 12
```